# Databricks and SQL server issue with token

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

I need your help to create a "permanently" connection from databricks to sql server database in Azure.
I have a code in pyspark to connect to database, using driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark" and JAR spark_mssql_connector_2_12_3_0_1_0_0_alpha.jar.
I have created a class to connect to DB is via token

```py
class SQLSpark():
    database_name: str = ""
    sql_service_name: str = ""
    service_principal_id: str = ""
    service_principal_secret: str = ""
    tenant_id: str = ""
    authority: str = ""
    state = None
    except_error = None

    def __init__(self, database_name, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret, tenant_id,
                 authority, spark, sql_service_name=None):

        self.database_name = database_name
        self.sql_service_name = sql_service_name
        self.service_principal_id = service_principal_id
        self.service_principal_secret = service_principal_secret
        self.tenant_id = tenant_id
        self.authority = authority
        self.state = True
        self.except_error = ""       
        self._spark_session = spark

        context = adal.AuthenticationContext(self.authority)
        token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials("https://database.windows.net", self.service_principal_id,
                                                              self.service_principal_secret)
        self._access_token = token["accessToken"]

        server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + self.sql_service_name + ".database.windows.net"
        self._url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + self.database_name + ";"


    def select_table(self, table, sql_query):
        try:
            logger.info(f"Reading table {table} in DB {self.database_name} ")
            df = self._spark_session.read.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
                    .options(
                    url=self._url,
                    databaseName=self.database_name,
                    accessToken=self._access_token,
                    hostNameInCertificate="*.database.windows.net",
                    query=sql_query) \
                    .load()

            self.custom_logger.info(f"Table {table} in database {self.database_name} has been read")
            return df
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f"Failed to read table  {table}")
            logger.error(ex)
```

The problem is that I have to process huge data and processes took more that 1h to process and database token expired. Is there a way to refresh the token when I call to `select_table` method?
Error given is:
`Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Token is expired.`

Full error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o9092.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 59.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 59.0 (TID 2611, 10.139.64.5, executor 0): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Token is expired. ClientConnectionId:009909b8-d779-4df2-b077-59cf4c4b3c73
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5173)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3810)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:94)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3754)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3053)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2562)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2067)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:825)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2519)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2466)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2668)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2656)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Token is expired. ClientConnectionId:009909b8-d779-4df2-b077-59cf4c4b3c73
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5173)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3810)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:94)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3754)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3053)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2562)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2067)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:825)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: you mean expiring during a single `select_table` or when you execute multiple `select_table` calls?

Comment: Seems like you want to keep track of the time you got the token and in `select_table` check the current time - if too much time has passed then invoke `token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials("https://database.windows.net", self.service_principal_id, self.service_principal_secret)` again.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I can think of.

1. Check if there is an option to provide a refresh URL to Spark. So it can get new token. Similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/access-adls1-from-sparklyr#solution) but for your SQL Server instead of ADLS. You'll probably have to use some other API like [acquire_token_with_refresh_token()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.authenticationcontext?view=azure-python#adal-authentication-context-authenticationcontext-acquire-token-with-refresh-token) to create the token.
2. I know some of the token generator implementations allow you to provide a requested expiry period while making the call to create a new token. If your does, then create a token valid for 2-3-6-whatever-you-need hours instead of letting it set expiry to default one hour.

---

Other option assuming your code is NOT correct. I.e. there is NOT a good reason to create token in `__init__()`. You should create token near where you use it. I.e.

```py
class SQLSpark():
    # ...

    def __init__(self, database_name, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret, tenant_id,
                 authority, spark, sql_service_name=None):

        # same as OP, except no token is created and stored in self.token

    def select_table(self, table, sql_query):
            # ...

            # Generate the token closer to it's use.
            token = adal.AuthenticationContext(self.authority).acquire_token_with_client_credentials("https://database.windows.net",
                self.service_principal_id, self.service_principal_secret)

            df = self._spark_session.read.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
                    .options(
                        # ...
                        accessToken=token["accessToken"],
                        query=sql_query) \
                    .load()
            # ...
```